# WatiN Web automation IE instance reshowing even Hide IE

Tags: c#, watin

i use this code for hide IE

```
WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide
```

in first time the browser hide and no problem,
but in next times browser show.

please help for force hide IE and not showing

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this setting before creating a Watin instance

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

Comment: thanks, but i used your code before create IE . in first time everything is OK, and when browser closed in end of operation and when i start operation again the browser showing !